# jQuery infinite scroll firing multiple ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I added some infinite scrolling from this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/) and i've been stuck on ajax request. it's always requesting multiple times.

[image: console img]

and this is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var win = $(window);
  var page = 1;
  var req = null;
  win.scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
      if (req != null) {
        req.abort();
      }
      req = $.ajax({
        url: "/member/member_c/generate_data",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          "page": page
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(msg) {
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
          if (obj.result) {
            $('#contentz').append(obj.data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify('page ' + obj.page + ' : ' + jQuery.inArray(page,done)));                                
            page = page + 1;
            req = null;
          }
        },
      });
    }
  });
});
```

i've been wondering, what is 'VM' at my console and why is what always firing a 'wrong' request?

Thanks

Comment: You're showing us a screenshot with log data but nowhere in your code are you logging. Please include all of the relevant code to produce exactly the output you're seeing (formatted so we can read it), but nothing that isn't necessary to reproduce the issue (a [MCVE], if you can). The `VM` in your console is the line number of the script in the source page.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're including two copies of your code somehow, since one call comes from your member_c.js file and the copies come from VM22* sources. You should show us your entire source code for the page with this problem, not just this single snippet.

Comment: but there's no any JS files in my source that named VMxxx or anything like that